# Making NetBeans Include Directories the IDE Knows About

Tags: c++, netbeans, include

I've been developing a lot in Java lately but I've been asked to look at switching one of my projects to C++ and I'm having a bit of trouble setting up the includes.  Unfortunately the extent of my C++ knowledge is a couple of academic projects I did in college.

I have created a project in NetBeans and I'm trying to add in some headers from an external library (pugixml).  I have

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"
```

at the top of the file I intend to use it in.  The problem is that when I compile I get

```
main.cpp:9:23: pugixml.hpp: No such file or directory
```

which seems odd to me seeing as the IDE definitely knows where the file is.  Code completion on classes from inside the library works and holding control and mousing over the file name shows me the correct directory where the file lives.  How do I convince the compiler to include this directory?

I know this really feels like something that should be easy to Google, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: `Unfortunately the extent of my C++ knowledge is a couple of academic projects I did in college.` Why are you trying to use C++ then? Is there a specific reason? If you're having such basic trouble I can tell you your project is probably going to be poorly written... no offense. We can't really answer this without knowing how you're trying to compile it or anything. But I'm going to say that netbeans is probably the least ideal editor for C++.

Comment: Agreed on all counts.  I made the people in charge aware of all these concerns, and they said that they believe this will be a good project for me to get started with.  As an interesting side note, I'm not the only one who looked at this and was puzzled by it.  The reason I'm using NetBeans, is the more experienced developers here are also using it.  We were assuming that this problem probably had something to do with one of the configurations I had messed with for Java development.

Comment: Just right click on the project -> Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Include Directories. Not very difficult.

Comment: Already did that.  That allowed the code completion to work and the IDE to know where the file was, but it doesn't seem to be sharing that information with the compiler.

Comment: Some compilers don't understand "/" as path separators which may be how Netbeans is currently specifying the paths to header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a makefile on linux:

check your makefile and add the -I Path_to_your_pugixml_hearders in the option of its compilation recipe.

or, add your path to the environment variable $CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. for example, in bash
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=Path_to_your_pugixml_hearder:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: Unfortunately this is Windows, but it does make me curious if there could be something to this.  I originally installed NetBeans as a Java IDE and added the C++ plugin later.  Most of the guys here who are using it, had the plugin at install time.  I wonder if there could be a missing environment variable that should have been created with the install.

Comment: Took a look at my system properties and I discovered that CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH was defined as a blank variable.  I removed it, rebooted, and now I'm good to go.  The answer here isn't quite right but I'll give it to him because he pointed me in the right direction.